# When adding approle to application it is throwing OData exception using Microsoft Graph API version 5 in C#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

```
var requestBody = new Application
                    {
                        AppRoles = new List<AppRole>
                        {
                           new AppRole
                            {
                                Id = CurrentRoleID,
                                IsEnabled = true,
                                AllowedMemberTypes = new List<string> { "User" },
                                Description = RoleModel.RoleDescription,
                                DisplayName = RoleModel.RoleName.Trim().Replace(" ", "_"),
                                Value = RoleModel.RoleName.Trim().Replace(" ","_")
                            },
                        },
                };

await graphClient.Applications[RoleModel.ApplicationID].PatchAsync(requestBody);
```

Tried this code but it is throwing an OData exception when I am trying to add App Role using Microsoft Graph API version 5 in C#.

Answer (score 0):

For adding Grant to an appRoleAssignment to a user:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new AppRoleAssignment
{
    PrincipalId = Guid.Parse("cde330e5-2150-4c11-9c5b-14bfdc948c79"),
    ResourceId = Guid.Parse("8e881353-1735-45af-af21-ee1344582a4d"),
    AppRoleId = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),
};
var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].AppRoleAssignments.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Can you please check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to add/Edit Roles in Application.